# Perforce repository changes in python

Tags: python, perforce, pvpython

I am rather new to perforce. So I need to get all revision history (e.g. which file, when, by whom was modified), using P4Python API. Can anyone guide me, at least what P4 command I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you're looking for is 'p4 filelog'. Here's the documentation: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/p4_filelog.html